# Unable to Switch Positions of Left and Right Divs in Flexbox Layout

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm working on a webpage layout where I have two divs, "left" and "right," within a flexbox container. Everything is working as intended, but I'm facing an issue with the positions of these divs. Despite trying different methods, I can't get the left and right divs to switch sides.

HTML:

```
<main class="main">
            <div class="left">
                <div class="about-us-text">
                    <h3>About Us</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="map-section">
                    <h3>Where to find us...</h3>
                    <div class="map-container">
                        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embe...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="how-it-works-image-container">
                    <img src="/Users/miguel/Desktop/Website/hiwfinal.png" alt="How It Works" class="how-it-works-image">
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    display: flex;
}

.left, .right {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.right {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.how-it-works-image {
  width: 70%; 
  max-height: 1500px; 
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.map-section, .about-us-text {
  width: 100%;
}

.map-container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 330px;
  border: 4px solid #317094;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.about-us-text {
  width: 70%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;}
```

What I've tried:

I've checked the syntax of both the HTML and CSS, and everything is structured correctly. The only problem is that the left and right divs are not switching positions as I intended. I have also tried clearing my cache, refreshing the page, and verifying the CSS file path, but none of these steps resolved the issue. The only warning in the console is about a missing favicon, which should not affect the layout.

Comment: Adding `flex-direction: row-reverse;` to your `.main` class will reverse the order of your divs. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: So, you want the divs to switch places?